# Text To Speech on native application android and ios

Tags: android, ios, cordova, text-to-speech

I wrote a Cordova application with a TTS provided by translation google REST services, that are no more available (from today I suppose) because they require a captcha to work. I have some questions about this:
- is possible to pay for the service? (Google translate API V2 don't seem the answer ...)?
- does [Android text-to-speech](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/speech/tts/TextToSpeech.html) work without internet?
- is there a Cordova plugin to connect this service?
- is it available something like this for iOS?

Comment: try this plugin https://github.com/macdonst/SpeechRecognitionPlugin, it uses android's SpeechRecognizer and iSpeech on iOS

Answer (score 5):

I will talk about the last question you asked. Yes there is offline TTS service for iOS. It's [AVSpeechSynthesizer](http://www.example.com/).

```
NSString *ttsString = @"Hello Bangladesh";
NSString *language = @"en-US";

AVSpeechSynthesizer *synth = [[AVSpeechSynthesizer alloc] init];
AVSpeechUtterance *utterance = [AVSpeechUtterance
                                        speechUtteranceWithString:ttsString];


utterance.rate = 0.5f;
utterance.voice = [AVSpeechSynthesisVoice voiceWithLanguage:language];
[synth speakUtterance:utterance];
```

You can see the list of language codes.

```
for(AVSpeechSynthesisVoice *voice in [AVSpeechSynthesisVoice speechVoices])
{
NSLog(@"%@", voice.language);
}
```

Answer (score 0):

I wanted to make a comment but my reputation is not enough. You can use SpeechRecognizer. It supports offline TTS utility for couple of languages including English, but not for all.

Actually it is both online and offline. If device is connected to a network then it uses online recognition communicating with Google servers. If device is offline then it uses offline package which is installed on the device.